# What is the difference between alias method and alias symbol?

Tags: ruby

I read some aliasing method like this:

```
alias :original_method :method
```

That looks like symbols in ruby for me. What's the difference if i typed that alias like this:

```
alias original_method method
```

Will the result be different?

Comment: You may or may not know, but just for your information. One thing to note here is that `alias` is not a method but is a keyword. If it were a method, then the second one would not work.

Comment: @sawa the first one wouldn't work either because of the missing `,` between arguments

Comment: @Stefan You are right. I missed that.

Answer (score 7):

There doesn't seem to be a difference, from the [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/doc/syntax/miscellaneous_rdoc.html#label-alias):

> The `alias` keyword is most frequently used to alias methods. When
>   aliasing a method you can use either its name or a symbol:
>
> ```
> alias new_name old_name
> alias :new_name :old_name
> ```

Comment: Hmm, Interesting. I would rather expect the former syntax to execute both methods and use their returned value. However, since alias is not a method but a keyword it makes perfect sense to behave differently. If you try to use method names instead of symbols for `alias_method` both methods are being executed.

Comment: Also, if `alias` were a method, then the first line would mean `self.alias(self.new_name(self.old_name()))` and not `self.alias(self.new_name(), self.old_name())`.

Answer (score 1):

Beyond the fact that one is a method (and so evaluates its arguments as any method does) you have to  leave the common use cases to find a difference.

For example if you do

```
class Foo
  def old_name
    'foo'
  end

  def self.rename_name
    alias_method :new_name, :old_name
  end
end

class Bar < Foo
  def new_name
    'bar'
  end
end

Bar.rename_name
```

Then `Bar` has its new_name method overwritten, and `Foo` is untouched

How ever, if you change this to use `alias` ie

```
class Foo
  def old_name
    'foo'
  end

  def self.rename_name
    alias :new_name :old_name
  end
end

class Bar < Foo
  def new_name
    'bar'
  end
end

Bar.rename_name
```

Then the `Bar` class is unchanged, and `Foo` gains a method called :new_name. This is not unlike the difference between using `define_method` versus defining a method with `def`.

In the one case the scoping is purely lexical: the location of the line calling `alias` completely determines what happens, whereas in the other case the it's the value of `self` when ruby evaluates that bit of the code.